# converting chrome extension to safari extension on excode I am getting this error {Optional(Error Domain=SFErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)")}

Tags: swift, safari-extension, web-extension

Steps to reproduce:-

1. Converted the chrome extension with this command (xcrun safari-web-extension-converter /path/to/extension)
2. Then after conversion, it opens in Xcode.
3. Then in the signing tab, I selected Team and bundle Identifier.
4. After this when I run the project "Quit and Open Safari Extension Preferences.." a dialogue box opens but when I click on that button it doesn't go to Safari extension preferences.
5. It gives error like this:- {Optional(Error Domain=SFErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)")}[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable the Develop menu in Safari and turn on the “Allow Unsigned Extensions” option?

Make sure to enable it and then it should show up.